# How to create variations from this import table

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to move products (with variations) from old system to woocommerce. I've successfully imported all products as simple products. Now I have the variations in the following format (as a csv table).

- SKU of parent product;Atribute Name;Values (separeted by comma);price
- 25;Size;S, M, L, XL;99

This allows me to easily add them as atributes using the import function. But I don't know how to make variations out of them quickly. Is there a way how generate variations out of all atributes for all products? Or import them somehow?

There is around 800 products and I don't want to do all of them manualy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by hiring someone on upwork, who created excel script/formula which generated all the variants in the csv file for the import. It cost me just $5 and took him like 20 minutes.

The import file looks like this:

- SKU;Parent product;Attribute 1 name;Attribute 1 value(s);price;type
- 25;(empty);Size;S, M, L, XL;99,variable
- (empty);25;Size;S;99;variation
- (empty);25;Size;M;99;variation
- (empty);25;Size;L;99;variation
- (empty);25;Size;XL;99;variation